# Custom JButton with JTextArea component inside

Tags: java, swing, click, jbutton, jtextarea

I extended JButton so it would fit my needs. I have one JTextArea and two JLabel components inside of my new class. The problem is, that I cannot click through JTextArea. So, when mouse is in JTextArea bounds, the button is not responding. There is no problem with labels.

As on screen. There are four buttons. Each one is a separate yellowish rectangle. When mouse is over JTextArea's gray rectangle, I cannot press the button. I need JTextArea because it supports multiple lines. Is there any option to make it not intercept the mouse?

It would be ok if I could attach ActionListener to JTextArea, but I can't. It cannot have this kind of listener.

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: *"I need JTextArea because it supports multiple lines."* So does a `JLabel` ..or a `JButton` for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

You look to be trying to use a JButton in a very non-button way, including having it hold a JTextArea, and not looking at all like a button. If you want a clickable area that is not an identifiable JButton, then consider using a MouseListener instead. You would likely have to add the same MouseListener to the container JPanel and the JTextArea.

Comment: I know that it's something very unusual, but I have other, normal buttons, that simply take ActionListener and I manage their calls in actionPerformed method. I was looking for some consistent way of collecting events. Dispatching event from mouse listener is an option, but takes time and extends complexity. And, as you mentioned, I will probably have to provide same listener for all components inside my new JPanel if I decide to go that way.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) to understand the difference between a renderer and an editor.

A renderer is a "rubber stamp" of the component, it is simply "painted" onto the surface of the `JTable` and is not a real life component

You would need to implement a custom editor, which could translate the trigger event (in your case the `MouseEvent`) into a local context.

Take a look at [`TableCellEditor#isCellEdtiable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/CellEditor.html#isCellEditable(java.util.EventObject)) which is probably the closest you will get to the source of the event which might trigger the cell to become editable.

`JButton` could be seeded with a `HTML` `String` (`"This is some text"), which would be capable of supporting multiple lines and line wrapping as well

Having said all that, you might want to seriously reconsider your design...